# Execute a THEN clause where WHEN is false

Tags: sql, hana, hana-sql-script

An error occurs in the code of `THEN` clause when a UDF is used in the `WHEN` clause, despite the fact that the function returns false.

```
-- a simple function for example
CREATE FUNCTION "is_one"
( 
      IN checkNum INTEGER
)
RETURNS is_one INTEGER
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
AS
BEGIN
    IF 
        :checkNum = 1
    THEN 
        is_one := 1;
    ELSE 
        is_one := 0;
    END IF;
END;

SELECT "is_one"(1) FROM DUMMY; -- returns 1
SELECT "is_one"(0) FROM DUMMY; -- returns 0

-- error...  [304]: division by zero undefined: cannot be divided by zero at function /()
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN "is_one"(0) = 1 THEN 1/0
        ELSE 0
    END AS x 
FROM DUMMY;

-- an error does not occur if the function is not used
-- returns 0
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN 0 = 1 THEN 1/0
        ELSE 0
    END AS x 
FROM DUMMY;
```

I expect the output to be 0, but the actual I get an error.

Comment: Seems like `1/0` is _always_ evaluated. Weird.

Comment: Is there a method in HANA that changes the behavior of function to be "deterministic"?

Comment: Apparently, isn't

Comment: Yes, SAP HANA 2 supports the `DETERMINISTIC` attribute for functions. But as written in the answer, this is not what is behind the unexpected behavior in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to recreate this with SAP HANA 2.40 and I did not get an error but the expected value 0